# Spring Transacional não está dando rollback quando é lançada alguma Excpetion

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Estou usando springboot 2.2.4 e mysql, como exemplo tenho duas classes: Cliente e Dependente:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "cliente", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Depentende depentende;
}
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class Depentende {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
...
    @OneToOne
    private Cliente cliente;
}

import br.com.acdev.clientes.repository.ClienteRepository;
import br.com.acdev.clientes.repository.DependenteRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ClienteService {
    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;
    @Autowired
    private DependenteRepository dependenteRepository;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Cliente criar(Cliente cliente) {
        cliente = clienteRepository.save(cliente);
        Depentende depentende = Depentende.builder().nome("joao").build();
        dependenteRepository.save(depentende);
        cliente.setDepentende(depentende);
        cliente = clienteRepository.save(cliente);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

no meu application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    password: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservas?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        show_sql: true
```

No meu service tentei forçar uma situação para dar rollback em tudo com qualquer exception, eu sei que poderia omitir o propagation e o rollbackfor, mas deixei explicito para ter certeza. Testei diversas variações nas chamadas de método, mas sempre que o executo, as entidades são persistidas no banco, mesmo com a runtimeexcpetion ou qualquer outra.

Comment: Você fez alguma configuração para utilizar corretamente o [PlatformTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html)?

Comment: não fiz nenhuma, além de @ Repository, @ Service e @ EnableSpringDataWebSupport
 na classe main

Comment: Você está usando jpa ?

Comment: @BrendonMiranda sim, usando import javax.persistence.* e no .yml está   jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        show_sql: true

Comment: Posta seu repository tbm